# systemd: Failed to start Sound Service

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 21.10

Once in a while, when I resume after suspending or restart the laptop, there are some issues with sound.

Under Sound tab in Settings, everything remains faded.

here's the output of `sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep -a "Nov  2" | grep -i -E "sound|audio"`

```
Nov  2 17:49:42 321go systemd[1820]: pulseaudio.service: State 'final-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Nov  2 17:49:42 321go systemd[1820]: pulseaudio.service: Killing process 9071 (pulseaudio) with signal SIGKILL.
Nov  2 17:49:42 321go systemd[1820]: pulseaudio.service: Killing process 9156 (alsa-sink-HDMI3) with signal SIGKILL.
Nov  2 17:51:12 321go systemd[1820]: pulseaudio.service: Processes still around after final SIGKILL. Entering failed mode.
Nov  2 17:51:12 321go systemd[1820]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Nov  2 17:51:12 321go systemd[1820]: pulseaudio.service: Unit process 9071 (pulseaudio) remains running after unit stopped.
Nov  2 17:51:12 321go systemd[1820]: pulseaudio.service: Consumed 17.878s CPU time.
Nov  2 17:51:13 321go systemd[1820]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Nov  2 17:51:13 321go systemd[1820]: Stopped Sound Service.
Nov  2 17:51:13 321go systemd[1820]: pulseaudio.service: Consumed 17.878s CPU time.
Nov  2 17:51:13 321go systemd[1820]: pulseaudio.service: Found left-over process 9071 (pulseaudio) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Nov  2 17:51:13 321go systemd[1820]: Starting Sound Service...
Nov  2 17:51:13 321go pulseaudio[22036]: Daemon already running.

Nov  2 17:51:13 321go pulseaudio[22036]: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
Nov  2 17:51:13 321go systemd[1820]: pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov  2 17:51:50 321go kernel: [ 1728.050401] snd_hda_codec_hdmi ehdaudio0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f8100. -5
Nov  2 17:51:51 321go systemd[1820]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov  2 17:51:51 321go systemd[1820]: Failed to start Sound Service.

Nov  2 17:51:51 321go systemd[1820]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Nov  2 17:51:51 321go systemd[1820]: Stopped Sound Service.
Nov  2 17:51:51 321go systemd[1820]: Starting Sound Service...
Nov  2 17:51:51 321go pulseaudio[22282]: Stale PID file, overwriting.
Nov  2 17:52:03 321go systemd[1820]: Started Sound Service.
Nov  2 17:55:59 321go systemd[1820]: pulseaudio.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Nov  2 17:55:59 321go systemd[1820]: pulseaudio.service: Killing process 22282 (pulseaudio) with signal SIGKILL.
```

```
> sudo lspci | grep audio
0000:00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)
```

I can't reproduce this issue.

Let me know if any other information is required.

Any pointers or solution will be helpful. Thanks.